# Best / neatest way to declare RelayCommands

Tags: c#, mvvm, readability, relaycommand

I've been trying to find a nice neat and succinct way to declare RelayCommands in my ViewModels.

The best I can come up with is:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ICommand StopCommand { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        StopCommand = new RelayCommand(OnStop);
    }

    private OnStop(object sender)
    {
         //hammertime
    }
```

}

What I'd really like to do it remove the two stage declaration/construction, something like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public readonly ICommand StopCommand = new RelayCommand(OnStop);

    private OnStop(object sender)
    {
         //hammertime
    }
}
```

However, this fails to compile with

> error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static
>   field, method, or property 'MyViewModel.OnStop(object)'

It there a neater / "standard" way that people use?

Comment: I've used the first format you specified quite a bit and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the first format you specified quite a bit and it works fine for me.

Also - if you're using WPF, binding doesn't work with fields anyway so even if you can get the second approach to compile, it won't hook up to your UI.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to abandon commanding which has it's limitations, and use another mechanism such as Actions provided by [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/). Then, you just need your view model verb:

```
public void Save()
{
}

<Button x:Name="Save">Save</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using something like:

```
 public ICommand StopCommand 
 { 
     get{return new RelayCommand(OnStop);}
 }
```

Comment: isn't it a good idea to use another private field which and check for null?